# Не работает обработчик прерывания

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc, прерывания

Почему этот код, меняющий обработчик прерывания клавиатуры, не работает на реальном компьютере (выводит символ 'A' только 1 раз), хотя нормально работает в эмуляторах bochs и qemu? Используется компилятор gcc, архитектура x86.

```
asm(".code16gcc\n");

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) FullAddr{
    ushort offset;
    ushort seg;
} FullAddr;

#define MAIN_CODE_START 0x9200

asm (
    "xorw %ax, %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    /*По этому адресу компоновщик помещает начало секции .data*/
    "movw (0x9202), %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ss\n\t"
    "movw $0xFFFB, %sp\n\t" 
    "jmp main"
);

void print_char(char c){
    asm volatile("int  $0x10" : : "a"(0x0E00 | c), "b"(7));
}

void get_int_addr(ushort interrupt, FullAddr *addr)
{
    asm volatile(
        "pushw %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w3, %%ds\n\t"
        "movw (%w2), %w0\n\t"
        "movw 2(%w2), %w1\n\t"
        "popw %%ds"
        : "=c"(addr->offset), "=a"(addr->seg):"b"(interrupt*4),"a"(0)
    );
}

void set_int_addr(ushort interrupt, uint func){
    asm volatile(
        "cli\n\t"
        "pushw %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w2, %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w0, (%w1)\n\t"
        "movw %%cs, 2(%w1)\n\t"
        "popw %%ds\n\t"
        "sti"
        : : "c"(func-MAIN_CODE_START), "b"(interrupt*4), "a"(0):
    );
}

void wait(uint usec)
{
    asm volatile("int $0x15": : "a"(0x8600), "c"(usec>>16), "d"(usec&0xFFFF));
}

FullAddr addr;

void handler_func(){
    print_char('A');
}

void handler();
asm(
    "handler:\n\t"
    "pushal\n\t"
    "call handler_func\n\t"
    "popal\n\t"
    "ljmp *addr\n\t"
    "iret\n\t"
);

void main(){
    get_int_addr(9, &addr);
    set_int_addr(9, (uint)handler);
    while(1){
        wait(1000);
    }
}
```

На всякий случай выкладываю [полный код проекта](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y53iwc34avhzoob/ar.zip?dl=0) , включающий образ дискеты (может, кто-нибудь запустит). Для компиляции нужно запустить файлы build.sh и build_main.sh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На [английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34490442/2586997) подсказали, что проблема в значении сегмента `%ds`, которое может измениться внутри обработчика прерывания 0x15 ( функция `wait`) в BIOS. И в этот момент может сработать прерывание 0x9, которое я перехватываю. А в обработчике последнего, как раз используется сегмент `%ds` (`ljmp *addr`). То есть, переход будет не туда, куда нужно.  Решение: каждый раз в функции `handler` менять `%ds` на своё значение, а в конце функции возвращать старое. Код:

```
void handler();
asm(
    "handler:\n\t"
    "pushw %ds\n\t"
    "pushal\n\t"
    "xorw %ax, %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "movw (0x9202), %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "call handler_func\n\t"
    "pushfw\n\t"
    "lcallw *addr\n\t"
    "popal\n\t"
    "popw %ds\n\t"
    "iretw\n\t"
);
```